# How to Import Time Zone Description Tables to MySQL/MariaDB in cPanel?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, cpanel, web-hosting

I was encountered with following error in **localhost** while setting MySQL timezone

> execute() failed: Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Asia/Karachi'

Then I imported the time zone description tables to `mysql` database using phpMyAdmin in **localhost**.
And error was resolved.

Now I am facing same error on **livehost** but `mysql` database is missing in **cPanel**.

So, how can I import MySQL time zone description tables in **cPanel**.

**Update**
Unfortunately command line `terminal` is not available in my shared hosting cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need **root** permission in MySQL to fix it. Because timezone info live in `mysql` system table.

If you have SSH access, you can apply this tip from official docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html
Run it in the shell command line

```sh
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

If you don't have shell permission, but you have root access to MySQL, you can store product of  `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo` in some other Linux host and then import it in cPanel's phpmyadmin as common sql script.

**Update:**

> Now I am facing same error on livehost but mysql database is missing in cPanel.

It seems shell access and mysql root password is your last chance to fix the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately command line `Terminal` is not available in my hosting cPanel